# Can't connect to Exchange 2016 from Outlook Client after Cumulative 13

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

We have an Exchange 2016 running on a Windows 2016 Server.  A couple of days ago, we decided to upgrade with Cumulative update 13 for Exchange.  However, after installing the update and rebooting the server, we can not connect to the Exchange server from our Outlook client.

The web interface works fine, and we can view all the email/public folders etc.  Any ideas why this is happening, as I can't see any errors in event viewer on our server?

[image]

I tried to accessing our Exchange server for a newer Outlook client and get the following message

[image]

If I click Next I get

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to ensure your autodiscover DNS records are correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, this error means Outlook's Auto Account Setup can't determine the correct settings to use. This is caused by incomplete or missing autodiscover records in DNS. As a result, you'll need to set your account up manually if you want to use encryption. See the following article for more information:http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/config/outlook-auto-account-setup-encrypted-connection-not-available/

If above doesn't help, try using Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer to test whether Exchange Autodiscover is working correctly:https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/